# Select data from two tables with connecting table

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, inner-join

I'm a bit confused with inner/left join.

I've got 3 tables:

```
users
-> id (PRIMARY with auto increment)
-> first_name
-> last_name
-> email
-> status

companies
-> id (PRIMARY with auto increment)
-> company_name
-> email
-> status

link
-> id (PRIMARY with auto increment)
-> user_id
-> company_id
-> status (if the connection is active)
```

I am trying to use the `link connection table` and then grab all data from `users` and `companies` that are connected with each other. Right now I am doing that in 3 steps, get the user_id then check link table and grab the company_id and then get the companies info.

Comment: Just learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  This is a SQL fundamental, so it really isn't appropriate for a question here.

Comment: About the confusion between INNER versus LEFT join, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38578/4003419) is an old SO post about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One SQL will do.
Just join them on the common keys.

```
SELECT 
 usr.first_name, 
 usr.last_name, 
 usr.email as user_email, 
 usr.status as user_status,
 comp.company_name, 
 comp.email as company_email, 
 comp.status as company_status,
 usrcomp.status as link_status
FROM users AS usr
JOIN link AS usrcomp ON usrcomp.user_id = usr.id
JOIN companies AS comp ON comp.id = usrcomp.company_id
WHERE usrcomp.status = 1
```